# Google Chrome App Kiosk open new window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode, google-chrome-os

I have build a ChromeApp that works perfectly. The App has a couple of links which onclick open a website in a new (browser)window.

If I put this App in Kiosk mode a new window will not popup.

I could not find more useful information about the ChromeApp kioskmode than this: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3316168?hl=en

Is it possible to open a new browser window in Kiosk mode. If so, how? If not, what is possible/blocked in Kiosk mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a new browser windows is not possible in kiosk mode on ChromeOS since there is no full browser running there, just your app's windows.